# Transient sectionNameKeyPath & NSSortDescriptor NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a list of tasks within Core Data. I fetch them into a UITableView using an NSFetchedResultsController.

I need custom sections in a custom order:

1. OVERDUE
2. ACTIVE
3. ONGOING
4. POSTPONED
5. COMPLETED

To determine what section a task should go in I use a derived transient attribute calculated on the fly based on other attributes in the relative object.

Unfortunately you cannot pass a derived value as a sort descriptor used by a fetch request.  This is because a fetch relies on already having data it is being asked to fetch. Chicken & Egg.

I understand why I can't do it, that doesn't help me solve the problem!

I've tried:

- Subclassing NSFetchedResultsController to '[customise creation of
  sections and index titles](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2)'. Maybe I'm doing this wrong however this just changes the names and orders of sections, not how many things go in those sections (which is critical).
- Populating arrays per section and feeding them to the table (clunky, 
  slow yet fully works).
- Ripping out ongoing & postponed tasks (which works, but isn't ideal).  This way I can sort by dueDate and drive the sectionNameKeyPath via the transient values.

Does anyone have any better ideas?  There are quite a few questions already just like this one yet none of them come to a neat solution.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: One option could be - if you are already fetching all tasks from Core data - maybe you could save extra atributes for each task - and if task "on the fly" changes section - it could also be updated in Core Data - thus - with animation repositioned in correct section by controllerWillChangeContent: delegate methods?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest solution is to add a persistent 'section' attribute (or convert your existing transient attribute). Make it a set of sortable values (which you display at runtime using the names you want). Whenever you update any record, recompute and store the section attribute as well.

I realize this sounds like you're storing redundant information but besides making your logic simpler, it will also be indexable which will speed access.

Comment: Hi Denis, thanks for your response.  As changing dates will move items into different sections, I wonder how I would check/change the section attribute efficiently?

Comment: This Answer +  Guntis Treulands' comment on my question works great :)